# How to prevent large rice noodle from curling?

Tags: asian-cuisine, noodles, thai-cuisine

Today I cooked big rice noodles with chicken in oyster sauce, Thai style. It was very delicious.

I had not fresh, but dried noodles (photo not mine).

[image]

In order to make it right, I needed to first cook the noodles in boiliing water for 2-3 minutes before actually stir-frying it, otherwise it would stay tough. But the instant I poured boiling water over it, all the nice rectangular sheets of noodles curled into noodle straws. How would I prevent that?

Comment: It might be from hydrating on one side only ... I'd try slowly dropping them (from the edge) into the hot water, and see how that behaves

Comment: @Joe: Instead of dropping the noodles into the boiling water, I actually poured the boiling water ON the noodles, so you might be right.

Comment: I would cook those noodles the same way I prepare wrappers for spring rolls - having a large pan of almost boiling water, and slide the noodles gently into the pan.

Answer (score 2):

I ate those kind of noodles as you showed once many, many years ago and IIRC those noodles taste like dried [Pho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pho) noodles and have the same texture. To stir-fry your noodles I suggest to soak them in cold or at maximum luke warm water first<sup>1</sup> and then stir-fry the softened noodles. Due to pre-soaking, hopefully there should be no uneven hydration and thus, no curling.<sup>2</sup> I've seen many people preparing Pho, [Hu Tieu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuy_teav) or sti-fried Pho that way without any curly noodles. 
Depending on how thick your noodles are you might have to blanch the noodles before stir-frying.

---

<sup>1</sup> For 30 minutes? I never paid attention to the time. They don't get mushy if soaked longer.

<sup>2</sup> YMMV: Another advantage: You might be able to prepare the noodles beforehand, so no blanching directly before stir-frying or having sticky noodles if not fried immediately.